# why do I see the horizontal scrollbar in the inspect (Ctrl+Shift+I) of the google chrome?

Tags: css, scrollbar, inspect

when I'm in the inspect state (press Ctrl+Shift+I on google chrome) in the google chrome there is a problem:
my page has a navbar menu, when I'm on the large screen there is no problem but whenever I resize the page, that navbar is shown in the right of the page(you can't see unless you scroll horizontally)
but I don't have this problem when I see my page normally without seeing the inspection of google chrome.
in the CSS I've hidden scroll horizontally (in the body I've written overflow-x: hidden)

I want to fix this issue because whenever an employer sees that in the inspect of google chrome that will not be so good.

Comment: Entering the dev tools resizes your window so you need to look to see what your code/CSS does on a narrower window. Without seeing the relevant code we probably can’t help you further so put a minimum example into a snippet, thanks.

Comment: Please provide some screenshots or a video of your problem or a link/code to demonstrate your issue visually